# FireFox inadvertedly increasing security?

Tags: cookies, anonymity, user-tracking, flash

With the known advent of Flash-based cookies and recently something called super-cookies, security and anonymity has become something more of a luxury rather than the norm and merchants want to super-track all of us whenever they can.

I was using FireFox the other day and noticed that the permissions bar wanted to run some Flash content so I clicked "Allow Now" and the page refreshed.

Upon refresh nothing new nor interactive was added to the screen.

Did FireFox thwart a tracking attempt?

Picture for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Firefox allows you to configure most extensions (including Adobe Flash) to always ask before running. That behavior is what you see here. Rather then inadvertently increasing security this is purposely meant to increase security. Once this is setup you will notice that many sites ask for flash player without any (visible) flash content. Many of these are tracking attempts, however I cannot comment on a single site without evaluating its flash content.

If you want to avoid flash tracking tell Firefox to always ask and only turn on flash when there is some Flash content on the page that you care about.

Comment: In Firefox 44 you actually can't choose to accept cookies on a site-by-site basis.  All or nothing.

Comment: @RoraZ Right, The question was asking about Flashplayer cookies which only work if Flashplayer is allowed to run for that site. If the Extension is set to ask it will only store data if allow the plugin to run.